# Is there an alternative to Twitter Storm that is written in Python?

Tags: python, bigdata, apache-storm

I couldn't find much after various searches, for an alternative to [Twitter Storm](http://storm-project.net/). Specifically a streaming big data processing library which doesn't use batching, e.g. Hadoop MapReduce uses batching.

Is there anything like this out there, that is 100% Python?

Comment: Interestingly, I was asking myself this same question recently, and I couldn't come up with any good answers. I'll be interested to see if anyone does have any good answers.

Comment: I have been using Storm for about two years now. It's amazing. When I looked around, I did not find a spec-by-spec alternative. I recently came across [Spark](http://spark-project.org/) it seemed pretty interesting. I am etching to use it in the next data mining project.

Comment: There is a project called [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), which can be used in a way similar to Storm.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from [Dremel](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/36632.pdf) I am not aware of any such tool that uses Python. But it is also not 100% Python, rather a mix of Python, C++ and Java.

Comment: Commenting on behalf of @nit: Dremel is used for interactive processing; do you have any use case to compare it with Storm?